# Run coded ui test from WPF application (without using mstest)

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests, testcontext

I want to run my coded ui test cases from a WPF application. However, when I initialize playback and call the test method, I am getting an error that the TestContext is NULL. Could anyone pls suggest if execution of coded ui test via WPF application is possible? Also, how can I access the TestContext in this approach as the test cases are data driven and I need to access TestContext.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing coded UI test from a standalone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482796/executing-coded-ui-test-from-a-standalone-application)

Comment: The requirement is to execute coded ui test from wpf application directly through code not using test agent or bat file.

Comment: Read the suggested duplicate again. There are several approaches offered, only one of them mentions "bat" and "agent". Please [edit] the question to show any additional requirements.

Comment: I am calling the Playback.Initialize, TestMethod and Playback.Cleanup in the right order. But the TestContext, when accessed, is null.

Answer (score 3):

#### This a behavior question of test runners

`TestConext` is populated at run time of the "TestHarness/TestRunner".
Its is an abstract class that in `Visual Studio` the process is called `QAagent32.exe` that supplies an implemented version for this based upon what your test method and class requires of it, e.g. Iterating data rows from a `Excel Worksheet`, `TFS TestCase` parameter data table; Coded UI, Unit Test.
If you want to use what is already used in `Visual Studio` you can just call `GetType()` on it, and research from there for its fully qualified type used. However, **IF** that class type isn't available you'll have to implement a concrete class that fully implements `TestContex`

Then in code you can do like the following:

```
PlayBack.Initialize();
var yourTestClass = new YourUniqueClassTests();
yourTestClass.TestContext = TestConextFactory.GetImplimentation();
yourTestClass.TestMethodThatsImportant();
```

Now if your using the [DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx) attribute on your test methods you will probably have to use reflection to pull that info.

```
var attribute= yourTestClass.GetType()
                            .GetMethod("TestMethodThatsImportant")
                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataSourceAttribute),false)[0] 
                             as DataSourceAttribute;
```

This should be able to get that data for you. Once you have it you could add logic to decide on what type of `TestContext` object you implement to set on the test class.