# is there any way to generate exe of Coded UI project?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have created one Coded UI project with some action, now I want to run those action without using VS. so I have tried this till now.

1.Created Coded UI project

2.recorded some action for test

3.Added new Console application project

```
    Playback.Initialize();
    CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1 codedtest = new CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1();
    codedtest.CodedUITestMethod1();
    Playback.Cleanup();
```

this is what i have done so far,

Above code is giving exception error in **Playback**

**Error** : An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll

I have added all the necessary dll files still facing same issue.

Note : there is some dependency so i can not use MsTest for this.

Comment: Try one click application.

Comment: can u explain it ?

Comment: Right click your solution, properties, publish tab

Comment: Publish option is not there

Comment: Unit test projects don't produce standalone .exe files, but are .dll instead. Use MsTest to run them.

Comment: @Alejandro i dont want to use MsTest for this

Comment: @SagarTrivedi Ok, but the idea is the same for whatever unit test framework you're using. A unit test project is fundamentally a "plugin" for a test runner, and its that test runner what picks your code and exercises it. Your code in itself never runs on its own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing coded UI test from a standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482796/executing-coded-ui-test-from-a-standalone-application)

Answer (score 0):

right click on solution>properties>configuration manager>configuration and set Configuration dropdown to release. save and exit properties. buid the project and after successfull build you will have in your release folder fully working exe app

Comment: In side release folder there is dll file and pdb file only.

Comment: release folder of console app?

Comment: post a screen shot of your solution explorer, you need to have a UI project that delegates tasks to a DLL.

Comment: well in that case you question is way too broad, you need to edit it and explain what your current code is doing.